# When sharing, Facebook wants me to provide a key hash, but what key hash do I provide when the app has been released on Google Play

Tags: android, facebook

When I tried sharing something to Facebook feed today via my Android app which has the FacebookSDK and a corresponding Facebook app in Facebook developers console, I got an error message:

```
Facebook key hash does not match any stored key hashes
```

Then I went to the logs in logcat, got the hash key from the error message, went to Facebook developers -> app and added it there.

Now I'm able to share posts.

But what do I do when I release the app to Google Play? What key hash do I have to add to Facebook so that all of my users are able to post on their Facebook Walls?

Comment: You need to provide FB with your release key hash. At the time of testing you provided only a Debug Key Hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1: Put the following method in your code (main activity or whatever).

```
/**
     * Generates the hash key used for Facebook console to register app. It can also be used for other sdks) Method copied from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/
     */
    public static String printHashKey(Context ctx) {
        // Add code to print out the key hash
        try {
            PackageInfo info = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                return Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            return "SHA-1 generation: the key count not be generated: NameNotFoundException thrown";
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return "SHA-1 generation: the key count not be generated: NoSuchAlgorithmException thrown";
        }

        return "SHA-1 generation: epic failed";
    }
```

Step2: In your `MainActivity`'s onCreate():`System.out.println("Fb key: "+printHashKey(this));`

Step3: Export your app APK, sign it with the same keyStore that was used to sign the APK that was uploaded to Google Play Store.

Step4: Install the APK on your device, connect it to your PC and look in LogCat for your `Fb key` to be printed.

Step5: Log in to Facebook, developer console, with the account that has your app attached. Under Settings, you can add the hash key that was printed out at Step4.

Comment: I will be able to award my bounty in 23 hours :) Thanks